# Django modelformsets contain no POST data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following model

models.py

```
class Activity(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    activity = CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    number = IntegerField(default=1)
```

and the following modelform

forms.py

```
class ActivityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['activity']
```

Made into a modelformset in the view

views.py

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(user=request.user)
ActivityFormSet = modelformset_factory(Activity, form=ActivityForm)
formset = ActivityFormSet(queryset=activities)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'save' in request.POST:
        formset = ActivityFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
```

My view stops here. Because the formset is not valid, and formset.errors gives me:

```
[{'activity': ['This field is required.'], 'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}]
```

from my template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for hidden in formset.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
    {% for activity in activities %} 
         <div class="expandable-input-small" id="input_activity{{ activity.number }}" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="form_activity{{ activity.number }}">{% for hidden in formset.form.hidden_fields %}{{ hidden }}{% endfor %}{{ formset.form.activity.as_hidden }}</div>
{% endfor %}
<button name="save" class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" value = "Click" onclick="get_data()">Save</button>
</form>
```

I use javascript to transfer data from the contenteditable to the hidden formset form field before submitting with the function get_data(). I have tested and confirmed that this function works by calling it outside the form and setting the input fields as not hidden.

No matter what I do - even if I unhide the fields and input data manually the formset doesn't seem to contain any post data. I've tried using the documentation to understand this - but most of the examples are (for some reason) taken from console commands, as opposed to displaying the formset in a template.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
 {% for activity in activities %}
```

you are looping through activities. However, you are not looping through forms in the formset. so,

```
{{ formset.form.activity.as_hidden }}
```

Is creating the same field each time, leading to missing fields in the POST

Try  something like

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for activity in activities %} 
        <div class="expandable-input-small" id="input_activity{{ activity.number }}" contenteditable="true">
        </div>
        <div id="form_activity{{ activity.number }}">
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                 {{ form.activity.as_hidden }}
                 {{ form.id.as_hidden}}
            {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button name="save" class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" value = "Click" onclick="get_data()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Which should give you the fields you need for each activity (matching the formset loop via count with the activities loop).  Normally, with a formset form, the hidden ID is provided automatically, but here, hopefully, creating it explicitly as_hidden will do the job.

Comment: This mostly works - the form content is now validated, but the ID is not, with the error {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}. Trying to experiment to see whether the error is missing from the POST-data (meaning the problem is in the template), or if it's not being recognized from the POST-data (problem in views - but I thought a modelform solved this automatically)

Comment: The form.id.as_hidden, eg name = 'form_0_id', should have a value the same as the activity.id - that's how the formset know which Activity the form is for.  You can output both in your template to make sure they match.  If they don't, let me know.

Comment: The value is the same - but I'm still getting the error. I assume this means the error is in the view?

Comment: I also see you've used both form2 (for management.form data) and formset. Should the management.form be for the formset instead?

Comment: Ah yes - that was a typo in this question actually (corrected it now). form2 is the actual naming convention I use in my template/view, i changed it to formset in order to make the question understandable.

Comment: I extended my code example to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: On further testing it seems that I was wrong - the value of form_0_id is not the same as the activity.id. In fact, the value corresponds to the id of another iterable I have, which again is connected to another formset. The code for this formset is more or less identical to the one in the example, with the exception of being connected to another modelform.

Comment: ...and I understand why it's happening. For some reason Django is rendering the formset forms with identical IDs across both of the formsets, so when the value is set for id_form_0_id for instance, it's set for both. If I could somehow change the "name" attribute of the formset and it's forms, this should fix the issue as the ID is based on the name (?)

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#customizing-a-formset-s-prefix and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view

Comment: Yes - I was missing a prefix when declaring the form on the back-end. Now everything works, thanks!